# Unable to connect with root because of skip-name-resolve option

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, configuration, connectivity

We had our MySQL server on an old server. We decided to move all of the databases to our new server.

- Old MySQL Server engine 5.5.31
- New MySQL Server engine 5.5.38

We created one general dump file without logs from all of the Databases in the *old server* and we restored the `.sql` file in the newly created MySQL Server on the new server.

On the new server when we put `skip-name-resolve` option in the `my.ini`  everything is fine but we can't login to MySQL server with root account.

*We tested the issue on old server and we didn't have any issue with `skip-name-resolve`*.

We removed `skip-name-resolve` option and we tried to login to MySQL server.
after login when we tried to list the available users. Like previous MySQL server here after restoring the dump we have two root users when we execute:

```
select user,host from mysql.user;
```

For the first one % is defined as host and for the second one LOCALHOST is defined as host.

All of the users are defined with % as their host. We want to use `skip-name-resolve` and on another hand resolve our issue with root account.

Answer (score 1):

The issue may be that you have 2 entries for `root`, and that `root@%` doesn't have the same password as the `root@localhost`. Changing options may change the order MySQL uses each entries.